# ng-html-bind omitting style tag

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-bind like this

```
<p ng-bind-html="decodeText(item.description)"></p>
```

with decodeText

```
$scope.decodeText = function (data) {
    return data
}
```

however, the following json loses the style attribute `style="color:#ff0000;"` when rendered

```
[{"title":"I am here","date_received":"Feb 28, 2014","description":"<p>EE)\u00a0 <span style=\"color:#ff0000;\"> accepted<\/span><\/p>\n<p>HH)\u00a0 <span style=\"color:#ff0000;\">I am\nhere; <\/span><strong>\u00a0<\/strong><\/p>"}
```

what's causing this?

Comment: Are you missing `$sce.trustAsHtml()`?  Should be `return $sce.trustAsHtml(data)`

Comment: Wow, that fix it! I was reading the docs for hours and I couldn't understand how $sce.trustAsHtml() is supposed to be used until you explained it. Thanks!

Comment: `ng-bind-html` and `$sce.trustAsHtml` are always used together for displaying flat HTML.

Comment: Cool! Now I know. You're a life saver! Thank you!

Comment: A made an answer in case others fall into the same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` and `$sce.trustAsHtml` are always used together for displaying flat HTML.

It seems you are missing the `$sce` part in your code.

Try this instead:

```
$scope.decodeText = function (data) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
}
```